# iOS Drawer UI that only works when breakpoint inserted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Following app [Drawer Demo](https://github.com/ksoftllc/DrawerDemo) does not work correctly until I add the breakpoint shown in the readme file. Without the breakpoint, the UI does not finish populating and the pan gestures are not recognized. With the breakpoint, everything works as designed.

The app has 2 view controllers: a parent vc and a drawer vc that is added to the parent with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BottomSheetViewController") as! DrawerViewController
    vc.configureDrawer(containerView: drawerContainer, overlaidView: overlaidView)
    drawerContainer.addSubview(vc.view)
}
```

**Solution** 
Had nothing to do with breakpoint, that was just a fluke. The issue as pointed out by @rob mayof is that the child and parent view controllers were not connected. Correct solution is marked below. For reference to others who may face this issue, the correct way to implement those is described by Apple at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html.

**Footnote**
This example was developed as an attempt to reproduce and isolate an issue in a much larger project. In attempting to do that, discovered this unexpected behavior and found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BottomSheetViewController") as! DrawerViewController
    vc.configureDrawer(containerView: drawerContainer, overlaidView: overlaidView)
    drawerContainer.addSubview(vc.view)
}
```

(Next time please include it in your question.)

You must tell UIKit that a view controller's view is in the hierarchy of another view controller's view by establishing a parent/child view controller relationship. Thus you need to add these lines:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BottomSheetViewController") as! DrawerViewController
    addChildViewController(vc)  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    vc.configureDrawer(containerView: drawerContainer, overlaidView: overlaidView)
    drawerContainer.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Comment: Did not know that.

Comment: Rob, I have edited the question per your suggestion and added a reference to Apple's documentation on container view controllers. You taught me something today. Thanks.